# How to update value in same table using mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to replace/update values in my table according att_id for each customer_id.
The table looks like:

```
ID att_id customer_id value
1  5            1     name
2  30           1     12345
3  40           1      
4  5            2     name2
5  30           2     12345
6  40           2
```

I'd like to replace it like this:

```
ID att_id customer_id value
1  5            1     name
2  30           1     
3  40           1     12345 
4  5            2     name2
5  30           2     
6  40           2     12345
```

Comment: What you've wrote so far?

Comment: Can you describe in words, what you are trying to do?

Comment: I need to find values for attribute 30, check if they are mobile phone numbers, and if it's true, write it itno value for attribute 40.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Based on your comments *...I need to find values for attribute 30, check if they are mobile phone numbers, and if it's true, write it itno value for attribute 40...* your query might look like this

```
UPDATE table1 t1 JOIN table1 t2
    ON t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
   AND t1.att_id = 40 
   AND t2.att_id = 30
   SET t1.value = t2.value
  --  ,t2.value = NULL -- uncomment if you need to clear values in att_id = 30 at the same time
 WHERE t2.value REGEXP '^[+]?[0-9]+$'
```

You might need to tweak a regexp to match your records ("mobile phone numbers") properly

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e96e8/1)** demo

---

It's hard to tell for sure from your description but if you need to swap values of `att_id` `30` and `40` per customer_id you may do something like this

```
UPDATE table1 t1 JOIN table1 t2
    ON t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
   AND t1.att_id = 40 
   AND t2.att_id = 30
   SET t1.value = t2.value,
       t2.value = t1.value
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8572c/1)** demo

or if you need to put values of `att_id = 30` to `att_id = 40` and "clear" values of `att_id = 30`

```
UPDATE table1 t1 JOIN table1 t2
    ON t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
   AND t1.att_id = 40 
   AND t2.att_id = 30
   SET t1.value = t2.value,
       t2.value = NULL
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a080e/1)** demo

Comment: But this does not really do the job of removing.

Comment: @MadanRam Sorry, removing what?

Comment: I mean you should remove ID=2 of value.

Comment: @MadanRam That's up to OP. The question isn't clear on that part.

Comment: @Alex Is it what you need?

Comment: @peterm One more thing. Can I filter in this query the condition if the value for attribute 30 a mobile phone number, than move it to attribute 40 and replace it with NULL(t2.value = NULL). And if t1.value an other phone number, than leave it unchanged?

Comment: @Alex That's what an updated query in my answer does if you uncomment a line with `,t2.value = NULL`. You just need to define what *mobile phone* is in terms of REGEXP.

Comment: @Aex How do you distinguish cell from other phone numbers?

Comment: @peterm By going through mobile phone starting numbers: WHERE t2.value LIKE '%0151%' OR LIKE '%0150%' etc.

Comment: @Alex OK, good. If it works for you then use these conditions for `WHERE` clause instead of REGEXP

Comment: Thanks again for your quick answer and pointing me on this great SQL Fiddle tool!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general approach for swapping the values on rows with `att_id` equal to 30 and 40:

```
update t join
       t t30
       on t.customer_Id = t30.customer_Id and t30.att_id = 30 join
       t t40
       on t.customer_Id = t40.customer_Id and t40.att_id = 40 join
    set t.value = (case when att_id = 30 then t40.value 
                        when att_id = 40 then t30.value 
                        else t.value
                   end)
    where att_id in (30, 40);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you remove the value of att_id = 30

`UPDATE tablename SET value="" WHERE att_id=30;`

Then set the value for att_id=40

`UPDATE tablename SET value="12345" WHERE att_id=40;`

Comment: Actually values can be different than "12345"

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tableName SET value=12345 WHERE ID=2;
UPDATE tableName SET value="" WHERE ID=3;
UPDATE tableName SET value=12345 WHERE ID=6;
UPDATE tableName SET value="" WHERE ID=5;
```

This are the command .See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-update-query.htm for tutorial on update.